# Append tuples in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

In the below part, I want to append in `self.data`  dictionary more **key, value `tuples`**.

Right now, when  a new `tuple` comes it goes on top of the current `tuple` and I am always left with the most recent one, while i want to keep all of them.

Any suggestions?

```
from datetime import date
from collections import defaultdict


class Budget(object):
    # todo : automatic date pickup

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.data = defaultdict(list)
        self.budget = None
        self.rem_days = None
        self.payment_dates = ['2019-01-23','2019-02-22','2019-03-22','2019-04-23','2019-05-23','2019-06-22',
                            '2019-07-23','2019-08-23','2019-09-23','2019-10-23','2019-11-22','2019-12-23',]
    def calc_days(self):
        cur_day = date.today().day
        cur_month = date.today().month
        ext_day = int(self.payment_dates[cur_month-1][8:10])
        self.rem_days = ext_day - cur_day+1
        print("Remaining days: ", self.rem_days)

    def daily_budget(self):
        self.budget = int(self.amount)/self.rem_days
        print("Daily budget: ", self.budget)

    def history(self):
        # todo: fill in the dictionary with multiple tuples
        imera = date.today()
        cur_month = date.today().month
        items = [self.rem_days, self.budget]
        self.data[str(imera)].extend(items)
        print (self.data)

inp = input("Insert account balance: ")
while inp != "s":
    budget = Budget(inp)
    budget.calc_days()
    budget.daily_budget()
    budget.history()
    inp = input("Insert account balance or / to stop:")
```

**output:**

```
Insert account balance: 54
Remaining days:  18
Daily budget:  3.0
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'2019-04-06': [18, 3.0]})
Insert account balance or / to stop: 54
Remaining days:  18
Daily budget:  3.0
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'2019-04-06': [18, 3.0]})
Insert account balance or / to stop:
```

Comment: please add code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `defaultdict` from `collections` module,

**Sample example:**

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
>>> d['foo'].append('bar')
>>> d['foo'].append('baz')
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'foo': ['bar', 'baz']})
>>> d['foo']
['bar', 'baz']

>>> data = defaultdict(list) 
>>> data["cur_day"].extend(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> data
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'cur_day': ['foo', 'bar']})
```

**Code fix:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

class SomeClass(Object): # python2 ?

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.data = defaultdict(list) # defaultdict for storing `data`
        self.budget = None
        self.rem_days = None
        self.payment_dates = ['2019-01-23','2019-02-22','2019-03-22','2019-04- 
                             23','2019-05-23','2019-06-22',
                            '2019-07-23','2019-08-23','2019-09-23','2019-10- 
                             23','2019-11-22','2019-12-23',]     


      def history(self):
        # todo: fill in the dictionary with multiple tuples
        cur_day = date.today().day
        items = (self.rem_days, self.budget) # made the items tuple
        self.data['cur_day'].append(items) # appending data to the `list` in `cur_day` of the `dict` `data`
        #self.data.update([("cur_day", items)])
        print (self.data)
```

Comment: still get 1 item in my list:
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'cur_day': [[18, 2.4444444444444446]]})

Comment: AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'extend'

Comment: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'2019-04-06': [18, 0.2777777777777778]})
Insert account balance or / to stop: 6
Remaining days:  18
Daily budget:  0.3333333333333333
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'2019-04-06': [18, 0.3333333333333333]})
Insert account balance or / to stop:

Comment: so again the dict is not populated, it always contains the last value of  self.data

Comment: It is called 2 times. I think this happens because the dict is extended with values that have the same key: '2019-04-06', so in the end I always have one key value pair, no matter how many times I call the "history method"

Comment: idealy if history is called twice, I want this:

 {'2019-04-06': [18, 0.2777777777777778],
 '2019-04-06': [18, 0.2777777777777778]}

Comment: Code updated. This also works:   {'2019-04-06': [(18, 0.2777777777777778), (18, 0.2777777777777778)]}

Comment: Just attached the output if "history" method is called twice

Comment: yes you're correct. Though "append" should be used and not "extend". Thank you